# Is $\Bbb Q$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, rational-numbers

It's an easy excercise in set theory to exhibit a bijection $\Bbb Q \cong \Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$. However, none of the bijections I'm aware of respect the topologies on $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q^2$, inherited from their respective embeddings into $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$.

Therefore, I'm asking whether there exists a homeomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Q^2 \to \Bbb Q$.

I don't believe that there is any such map, but since the standard techniques of algebraic topology don't enable one to discern between $\Bbb Q$ and a discrete space, I wasn't able to prove it. Maybe Cech cohomology provides a means to attack this problem, but I haven't even got the slightest Iiea how to calculate $H^1(\Bbb Q,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Can't you just take the usual product topology from the embedded topology on Q?

Comment: That's the same.

Comment: Here's the answers you're looking for: 

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26001/are-the-rationals-homeomorphic-to-any-power-of-the-rationals

Comment: There might be better duplicates. This was the first one I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of the rational numbers with its usual topology is the unique countable metrizable space without isolated points.

Can you use that property to conclude?

Comment: Of course, you need to [prove](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm) that characterization of $\mathbb Q$ :-)

Comment: Thanks. However it would be also nice to see an explicit construction.

Comment: Well,you were considering to use Cech cohomology...